# Is WAKELOCK set per application or activity

Tags: android, android-wake-lock

When setting the wake lock flag using `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` does that set the WAKELOCK for the whole application or just that activity. So for example I have set it in my main activity, the only place it's required, and the in the `onPause()` of that activity removed it. Do I need to remove it in the `onPause()` of every activity in the app or just that on where it is set.

All I could find in the documentation is that you should only ever set it in an activity not a service etc but it doesn't seem to say what it effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear `WAKELOCK` is set per application. Tested by setting, opening a different activity and leaving it to time out - which it didn't.